Robot teleoperation using HTC Vive tracker
i am working on controlling UR5 robot using only HTC vive tracker (no headset, no vive controllers...)
I'm currently on ROS Noetic (Ubuntu 20.04)
How can i achieve this and where can i find related documents ?
